# How can I search a listbox and save all the results in another listbox?

Tags: vb.net

for now, i am using this code but it doesnt give me what i want..
for example i want to list all the items with the string "1"

```
Dim x, count As Integer
x = ListBox1.Items.Count
count = 0


Do While count < x
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.FindString("1") Then

        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items(count))

    End If
    count = count + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: VB.net, sorry for incomplete post..

Comment: What UI? Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
      {
        if(s.contains("1"))
        listbox2.add(s);
      }
```